# Add Random CSS on Each Instance of a Class With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random, positioning

What I need to do is add one of three CSS styles to every instance of `.project_content` in my HTML, and the style needs to be picked at random for each instance.

The three styles are as follows:
`float:left`
`float:right` OR
`margin:auto` + `width:x` (where the width of `.project_content` is calculated and `x` is the calculated width)

Right now I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var floats         = ["right","left"];                
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*floats.length);           
  $('.project_content').css("float", floats[rand]);
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</script>
```

All this script is doing for me is applying `float:left` or `float:right` to ALL instances of `.project_content` instead of choosing right or left for each instance.

How do I get my script to pick a random variable for each instance of `project_content` and how can I add the `margin:auto` + calculated `width` into the mix? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get a random style for *each* element in the set, instead of a single random value for the *entire* set. That can be done using [`.css( propertyName, function(index, value) )`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2), since the function gets called for *each* matched element:

```
$('.project_content').css("float", function () {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * floats.length);
  return floats[rand];  
})​;
```

​
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pWpAB/)**.

To add `margin` and `width` into the mix, you can no longer use `css()` (since you need to  modify one of multiple properties), but you can do it using `.each()`:

```
var styles = [ "left", "right", "margin" ];
$('.project_content').each(function () {
  var randomStyle = styles[Math.floor(Math.random() * floats.length)];
  if (randomStyle == "left" || randomStyle == "right") {
    $(this).css('float', randomStyle);
  } else { // margin
    $(this).css('margin', 'auto')
           .css('width', your_calculated_width);
  }
})​;
```

Comment: A little side note on this solution. You can get attributes of the relevant DOM element like this:
`$('element').css({left:function(){return $(this).attr('original-x');});`